# Adding top padding to UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to add top padding to a text field, but could not find anything useful, all solution were about left and right padding which I already know about. To make things clear, I want to make it like the image below.

Note: I used label for "Description" and I have put it within the text field, but label and input overlapped.

[Text Field Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpFad.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a customTextField class

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0);

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }
}
```

**Swift 4 version**, as per Micah's answer below:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0);

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I delete my text field from the storyboard and create new one programmatically using this class? or is there another way?

Comment: No, Just set the custom class from your Storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to the accepted answer, note that for Swift 4 you will need to change

```
return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
```

into

```
return bounds.inset(by: padding)
```

Comment: I used it in Swift 4 and had to use UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect or it gave an error